# Android: get all contacts by IM

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

I want to query to Contacts content provider such that if a contact has IM whose type is equal to "XYZ".

I tried below way but I am not getting any result:

```
    Uri uri1 = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection1 = null;
    String selection1 = null;
    String[] selectionArgs1 = null;
    String sortOrder1 = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor1 = context.getContentResolver().query(uri1, projection1, selection1, selectionArgs1, sortOrder1);
    if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            int contactId = Integer.parseInt(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));

            Uri uri2 = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection2 = null;
            String selection2 = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs2 = new String[]{"XYZ", contactId + ""};
            String sortOrder2 = null;
            Cursor cursor2 = context.getContentResolver().query(uri2, projection2, selection2, selectionArgs2, sortOrder2);
            if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                }
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor2);
            }
        }
        cursor1.close();
    }
```

I am not getting any log with above code.

**PS:** I am not using built in protocols like AIM, Windows Live, Yahoo or skype. Its my custom Protocol, say it "XYZ".

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to query the `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` and with the mime type as IM and then the label or type field (not sure) holds that which type of IM like you said 'XYZ' and in the value column you will get the value like a username.

There is a foreign key in this table which is linked to raw contact id of raw_contacts table.

**UPDATE**

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String value = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));

                //Types are defined in CommonDataKinds.Im.*
                int imppType = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));

                //Protocols are defined in CommonDataKinds.Im.*
                int imppProtocol = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL));
                //and in this protocol you can check your custom value
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Some snippet would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem. Turns out that the protocol should be an `Int` instead of a `String`. In case of being a custom one you should use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM` which is an alias for `-1`.